# AS3 referencing a list item which has no name

Tags: list, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
list.addItem({label:"a"});
```

When you add an object to the list like this, how do you reference to it later without using a listener for the list and then going

```
list.selectedItem
```

Are list items not indexed like arrays? I would want to do something like this

```
   trace(list.item[0].label);
```

And have it return "a" Is this not possible with lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.dataProvider.length // gets total number of items
list.dataProvider.getItemAt(0) // gets first item
list.dataProvider.getItemAt(0).label // gets the first item label
```

See all the methods here..
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html

Comment: Easiest way to figure test that those items aren't undefined. trace(txtPersonVelg.text) trace(txtPersonVelg.text) trace(personListe.dataProvider.getItemAt[0])

Comment: Sorry typed brackets instead of parantheses like this `list.dataProvider.getItemAt[0] instead of list.dataProvider.getItemAt(0)`